# Help showing an inequality holds over a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence that converges to $L> 0$ . Show that, if $M$ is a real number such that $L>M >0$ , then eventually $x_n>M$ (in other words, show that the exist an $M$ (natural numbers) such that for every $N\ge n$ $(x_n>M)$

I have no idea how to start this or solve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: start by reading the definitions one more time if necessary, and taking $\varepsilon=L-M$

Answer (score 0):

Set $\epsilon = (L - M)/2$. Then $\epsilon > 0$. Since $x_n\to L$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $x_n > L - \epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$, i.e., $x_n > (M + L)/2$ for all $n\ge N$. Show that this implies $x_n > M$ for all $n\ge N$.